# Playing mp3 files in my Django 1.11 Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

So I am having trouble playing mp3 files on my Django application.

settings.py - Added MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URLS

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

models.py - I have a simple audio class setup

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    featured_image = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py - Here is my view

```
class AudioListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'audio'
template_name = 'media/audio/audio_list.html'
model = Audio
```

audio_list.html - Here is my template

```
{% block content %}
{% for aud in audio %}
<p>Audio Title: {{ aud.title }}</p>
<img src="{{ aud.featured_image}}" alt="">
<hr>
<audio controls>
<source src="{{ aud.audio_file }}" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<hr>
<p>Audio Description: {{ aud.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I can go in and add an audio file and it uploads to the following directory

```
# myapp -> uploads -> audio -> audio.mp3
```

With the following setup the html5 audio player doesn't even show up. When I check the source for the page I get the following:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

I have combed through the Django documentation. I have searched all over google. I wouldn't think it would be that hard to pull a file path and play it.

Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: Add my url files

```
# mainapp/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.flatpages import views
from home.views import HomeTemplateView


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('home.urls')),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^media/', include('media.urls')),
url(r'^about/', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about/'}, name='about'),
url(r'^contact/', views.flatpage, {'url': '/contact/'}, name='contact'),
url(r'^donations/', views.flatpage, {'url': '/donations/'},  
name='donations'),]

# media/urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from media.views import AudioListView, VideoListView

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^video/$', VideoListView.as_view(), name='video'),
url(r'^audio/$', AudioListView.as_view(), name='audio'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**First: You need to get all audio files**

```
class AudioListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'media/audio/audio_list.html'
    model = Audio

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AudioListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['audio'] = Audio.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Then you need url:**

```
<source src="{{ aud.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
```

**Change Permission of Directory** to see player on page.

```
chmod a+r -R uploads
```

Comment: The html5 player still does not show up. I think it might have something to do with my urls setup. I will append those files to my original post.

Comment: when I check the source for the page i can see that the path shows up. <source src="/uploads/audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> The file is in that directory but the player does not show up.